# Get index of date with max years and min month

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset of 3 variables: `ID`, `Date` and `Years_service`. Like this:

```
library(data.table)
data <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Date = structure(c(1230768000, 
1233446400, 1235865600, 1238544000, 1241136000, 1243814400, 1246406400, 
1249084800, 1251763200, 1254355200, 1257033600, 1259625600, 1262304000, 
1264982400, 1267401600, 1270080000, 1272672000, 1275350400, 1277942400, 
1280620800, 1283299200, 1285891200, 1288569600, 1291161600, 1293840000, 
1296518400, 1298937600, 1301616000, 1304208000, 1306886400, 1309478400, 
1312156800, 1314835200, 1317427200, 1320105600, 1322697600, 1325376000, 
1328054400, 1330560000, 1333238400, 1335830400, 1338508800, 1341100800, 
1343779200, 1346457600, 1349049600, 1351728000, 1354320000, 1356998400, 
1359676800, 1362096000, 1364774400, 1367366400, 1370044800, 1372636800, 
1375315200, 1377993600, 1380585600, 1383264000, 1385856000, 1388534400, 
1391212800, 1393632000, 1396310400, 1398902400, 1401580800, 1404172800, 
1406851200, 1409529600, 1412121600, 1414800000, 1417392000, 1420070400, 
1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400, 1433116800, 1435708800, 
1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 1448928000, 1451606400, 
1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 1464739200, 1467331200, 
1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000, 1330560000, 1333238400, 1335830400, 
1338508800, 1341100800, 1343779200, 1346457600, 1349049600, 1351728000, 
1354320000, 1356998400, 1359676800, 1362096000, 1364774400, 1367366400, 
1370044800, 1372636800, 1375315200, 1377993600, 1380585600, 1383264000, 
1385856000, 1388534400, 1391212800, 1393632000, 1396310400, 1398902400, 
1401580800, 1404172800, 1406851200, 1409529600, 1412121600, 1414800000, 
1417392000, 1420070400, 1422748800, 1425168000, 1427846400, 1430438400, 
1433116800, 1435708800, 1438387200, 1441065600, 1443657600, 1446336000, 
1448928000, 1451606400, 1454284800, 1456790400, 1459468800, 1462060800, 
1464739200, 1467331200, 1470009600, 1472688000, 1475280000), class = 
c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), Years_service = c(19, 19, 19, 19, 
19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 
23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 
9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13), 
month_1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)), .Names = c("ID", "Date", 
"Years_service", "month_1"), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = 
c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want a new variable that contains for each ID the date for which years of service is maximum and the month of date is minimum. Something like this:

```
     ID       Date Years_service    Date_1
  1:  1 2009-01-01            19    2016-06-01
  2:  1 2009-02-01            19    2016-06-01
  3:  1 2009-03-01            19    2016-06-01
  4:  1 2009-04-01            19    2016-06-01
  5:  1 2009-05-01            19    2016-06-01
 ---                                          
  146:  2 2016-06-01            12    2016-08-01
  147:  2 2016-07-01            12    2016-08-01
  148:  2 2016-08-01            13    2016-08-01
  149:  2 2016-09-01            13    2016-08-01
  150:  2 2016-10-01            13    2016-08-01
```

My desired output is `Date_1`

I tried this:

```
data[,Date_1 := Date[which.max(Years_service) & which.min(month_1)], by = ID]
```

but didn't work.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I know my try was wrong. I showed just in order to give an  example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to get the row index (`.I`) of the rows where the 'Years_service is `max` for each 'ID', then using that, get the `min`imum index of 'month_1' to subset the 'Date' corresponding to that value grouped by 'ID', and join `on` with the original data on the 'ID' column to create the 'Date_1' column

```
i1 <- data[, .I[Years_service == max(Years_service)], ID]$V1
data[data[i1, Date[which.min(month_1)], ID], Date_1 :=V1, on = .(ID)]
data
#     ID       Date Years_service month_1     Date_1
#  1:  1 2009-01-01            19       1 2016-06-01
#  2:  1 2009-02-01            19       2 2016-06-01
#  3:  1 2009-03-01            19       3 2016-06-01
#  4:  1 2009-04-01            19       4 2016-06-01
#  5:  1 2009-05-01            19       5 2016-06-01
# ---                                               
#146:  2 2016-06-01            12       6 2016-08-01
#147:  2 2016-07-01            12       7 2016-08-01
#148:  2 2016-08-01            13       8 2016-08-01
#149:  2 2016-09-01            13       9 2016-08-01
#150:  2 2016-10-01            13      10 2016-08-01
```

---

Or extract the 'Date' corresponding to minimum 'month_1' from within the Subset of Data.table

```
data[, Date_1 := .SD[Years_service == max(Years_service), 
                  Date[which.min(month_1)]], ID]
```

---

Or another option is to an `order` and assign 'Date_1' as the `first` 'Date' grouped by 'ID'

```
data[order(-Years_service, month_1), Date_1 := Date[1], ID]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   arrange(desc(Years_service), month_1) %>%
   mutate(Date_1 = first(Date))
```